# How to pass jsp String variable value in javascript and print there

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Hi i want to use jsp variable  value  in javascript  How can i use

Here is my code.

`Demo.jsp`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        String plane="A";
        %>
        <script>
     var planB=<%=plane%>;
     c
     if(planB==B){
     document.write("shakti");
     }else{
     document.write("sharma");
     }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i get  my desired  output

Comment: try `var planB='<%=plane%>';`

Answer (score 1):

Change your script block with the following:

```
<script>
    var planB = '<%=plane%>';
    if(planB === 'B'){
        document.write("shakti");
    } else{
        document.write("sharma");
    }
</script>
```

Changes:

- Your jsp variable should be inside single (or double) quotes, otherwise you'll get an error: "A is undefined"
- You have a character 'c' in the script-block, that'll also throw a javascript error.
- I've changed '==' to '===' (in the if-check), so that you not only check the values, but also the types.
- You have to place 'B' (in the if-check) between single (or double) quotes, otherwise you'll get an error: "B is undefined". You want to compare the variable to a string, not a variable ==> place inside single (or double) quotes.